# jQuery or $, problem situations

Tags: jquery

Could someone list some real life examples of conflicts using $ sign instead of jQuery.

As i have heard, it can create issues if another js library(ies) are used.

So better to use jQuery for jQuery plugins?

Some links to detailed explanations are welcome. :)

Thanks ;)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If jQuery is the only Javascript library you're using, then go ahead and use `$`, it won't hurt.

If you're using more than one Javascript library (which honestly, I wouldn't recommend, but hey, up to you), then you have a couple of options:

1. Use jQuery in [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode, and reference it as `jQuery`.
2. Use jQuery in [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode, and scope the usage of `$` via closures, like so:

---

```
(function($) {
    // bunch of code using $ to refer to jQuery here
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Interesting example with closures. Any disadvantages using this solution? If not going out of scope, everything gona be ok i guess. Thanks mate ;)

Comment: Aside from having to explicitly specify, no, there's not really any disadvantage.

Answer (score 1):

The problems that you might get have to do with the use of the same namespace **$** (or other, depending on the code).

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 0):

$ tends to be a common identifier for some Javascript libraries used to call functions.

If you include jQuery, then some other library that overwrites the $ property on the window, you lose jQuery. It's only problematic if you're using it with other libs, or your own code which changes what $ does.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it better to use jQuery. For example, Prototype library uses the $.